# How to select a specific sprite and move it in SDL

Tags: c++, sdl

I'm making a chess game, where I have a box shaped selector, now I want to select a sprite with that box and move it in a specific location with the selection box.

Any link or code?

[image: Selector and the sprite image]

Comment: So are you asking how to map from some screen position to one of your objects? That should be simple (assuming you keep track of where on the screen your objects are). Or something else?

Comment: How is your rendering set up? With surfaces? Or with a renderer and textures?

Answer (score 0):

You keep track of the position of everything.

Poll for events, see where the mouse is. If in the rectangle of a piece, put the selector on top of the piece (assuming you have colorkeying or alpha). You should be able to listen to keyboard input and move the selector based on that.

When mouse clicks, see where the selector is. Find the piece that's under it, and remember it.
When mouse clicks again, see where the selector is now. Check if moving there is valid. If yes, move the piece you remember to the new position.